# Translate a full website with the google translate API

Tags: php, google-api, google-translate

is it possible to translate a whole website by using the google translate api?

for example:
You can paste an URL here https://translate.google.com/
and google translate the whole website for you.

i want to do the same with php.

**I give google this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>House</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="redCar">A red car.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and google translate it to (for example german)
**response:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Haus</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="redCar">Ein rotes Auto.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Possible? I found only the way to translate words and sentences.